# "Open PDFs from last session on Acrobat launch" is disabled

Tags: adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader, system-preferences

In the acrobat reader, the option of `"PDFs from last session on Acrobat launch"` is disabled, such that it cannot be checked anymore.

See the screenshot below.

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Uninstall Acrobat Reader, restart, download the newest Reader version from the Adobe Website, install and test the option.

Comment: @John , I'm goifing to do this and will say the result.

Comment: @John , In the new version I recently installed (`version 23.003.20244`), although it is possible to check this option, when I reopen the file, it always opens from the first page, regardless of where the PDF file was last closed.

Comment: So the option now works (Your Question).  I do not know about your second question because the option only deals with opening the PDFs open from the last session.

Comment: @John , I assumed by this option if the PDF file closes on page say 20, then when reopening the file, we'll see the page 20, while it is not the case and always the file opens from the first page... So I do know what is the use case of this "option" ...

Comment: @John , I found the right option.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Acrobat Reader, restart, download the newest Reader version from the Adobe Website, install and test the option.

That should fix the main option (was greyed out).

You have also found the option to retain the page number of the PDF file. so my answer is helpful here.